# Flutter TextFormField enabled sharedpreferences

Tags: flutter, boolean

i want to make false or true TextFormField enabled property. I try to get false or true value from sharedpreferences. I am saving **ifLogged** value "**true**" while app is opening.

So, I am using ifLogged value one of my screen. 
My problem is; **isLogged** parameter first time false, secondtime true.

```
  bool isLogged = false;

  Future<bool> checkLogin() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    isLogged = (prefs.getBool('ifLogged') ?? false);
    return isLogged;
  }

 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    checkLogin();
  }


TextFormField(enabled: isLogged ? true : false,
...
```

Is there any problem about `bool isLogged` between `Future<bool>`

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is natural because it takes some time until a future completes so at first it is `False` and when the future completes it becomes `True`/`False`(data saved in your preference).

Something you can do is to show the user that the data is fetching like this:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Home());
}

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  Future<bool> checkLogin() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return (prefs.getBool('ifLogged') ?? false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<bool>(
      future: checkLogin(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<bool> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData)
          return Center(
            child: TextFormField(
              enabled: snapshot.data,
            ),
          );

        return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      },
    );
  }
}
```